# Combine a running balance statement as a column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two Select Statements which are collecting data from 1 table, one is a totals select statement. Could anyone assist me with combining them into 1 statement? Any assistance is appreciated

**Statement 1**

```
SELECT ClientId, ExternalBank, PlacementDate
FROM tblDepositTransactions where ID = 15
```

**Statement 2**

```
SELECT Sum(EffectiveAmount) AS RunningBalance
FROM tblDepositTransactions WHERE ID = 15 GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ClientId, ExternalBank, PlacementDate,(SELECT Sum(EffectiveAmount)
FROM tblDepositTransactions WHERE ID = 15 GROUP BY ID)as RunningBalance
FROM tblDepositTransactions where ID = 15
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very for your quick response.